# How To Create 'Hard Plastic' Material?

Tags: texturing, materials, node-editor

I'm new in texturing and I've been trying to create materials for my pistol model. However, for the grip part the plastic texture is undesirable as it is way too smooth when rendered. Ideally I want the material to look like this.
[image]

But for my own texture it looks like this.

[image]
[image]

How should I create the plastic material to make it look realistic? (With roughness on the surface) I have gone through the Internet but the tutorials mainly focused on creating glossy plastic which is not the one I need. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## Breakdown

Rough hard plastic or similar materials with slightly irregular surface textures should obviously have some sort of displacement.

Also, even if they are rough, they still have some sort of glossiness but it's more evenly distributed.

## Base Material

The base material (blue box) consists of a diffuse color bsdf to control the base color, a glossy Beckmann bsdf to control the glossy color. The roughness that should be slightly below 0.5, everything above gets too evenly distributed and everything below generates too sharp glossy areas. The mix shader should have a factor that puts more stress on the gloss (0.75).

## Displacement Material

The displacement material (yellow box) also generates some variation to the diffuse color. The Voronoi Cell Texture with a high scale is always handy when it comes to nice uneven distributed surfaces. It needs a Texture Coordinate node, since it gets generated per object and a Gamma Node to control the intensity.

## Material Mix

Both the base material and the displacement material go into a mix shader. The gamma-corrected color value of the Voronoi Texture also gets connected to the displacement value of the Material Output node.

## Node Setup

[image: node setup]

## Result

[image: result]

Comment: This material is what I'm looking for, thank you so much for the detailed answer.

Comment: @Mr.Benson - you're welcome. Detailed descriptions about material setups and detailed observations about a material's properties  should go hand in hand IMHO.

Comment: Afaik it's better to mix those diffuse and glossy using Fresnel, plastic in particular.